# How can I use a parameter other than the document id in an iron-router path

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I currently have the below route and it works great. I want to change the path that is being used to a different id that is inside the same document (not a mongoDB generated id). How can I change this route to use a different id in the path?

```
this.route('thanks', {
      path: ':root/thanks/:_id',
      waitOn: function() { 
        return Meteor.subscribe('donate', this.params._id)},
      data: function () {
        var root = Meteor.settings.root;
      return Donate.findOne(this.params._id);
          },
      action: function () {
          if (this.ready())
              this.render();
          else
              this.render('Loading');
      }
  });
```

In my client side code I do this to return the page.

`Router.go('/give/thanks/' + result);`

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the parameter you want in the route parameters:

```
 Router.go('thanks', {root: 'give', _id: something._id});
```